# Read lines to array of strings

Tags: c, file, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make function that fills array of strings with lines from file, but the compiler (GCC) still giving me a warning. Than if I try to run compiled app, it gives me "Segmentation fault" error
Source code:

## main

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "getAdresses.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
        char adresses[1024][128];
        getAdresses(adresses);
        printf("%s", adresses[1]);

}
```

## getAdresses

```
include <stdio.h>

int getAdresses(char **adresses){
        FILE *fr;
        fr = fopen("adresses", "r");
        int i = 0;
        while(adresses[i-1][0] != EOF){
                fscanf(fr, "%s\n", &adresses[i]);
                i++;
        }
}
```

It's giving me this error:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘getAdresses’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from main.c:3:0:
getAdresses.h:1:5: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[128]’
```

Comment: And so a two-diemensional array strikes again...

Comment: AFAIKT it's "just" a warning, so the code should at least work. I just think it's not a good idea to read unbound from the file. What do you think will happen if you  try to read more then 1024 "strings"?

Comment: the compiler told you what you did wrong. Its a warning because its possible the you mean to pass the wrong type, but if you dont understand the warning then you should treat it as fatal.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have done the typical mistake: `char **` is **not** the same as a `char (*)[128]`. The latter is the type of `adresses`.

You get the segmentation fault when you try to dereference it in line

```
while(adresses[i-1][0] != EOF)
```

Aside from the fact that adressing `[i-1]` for `i = 0` will give you bad results you should define your function as

```
int getAdresses(char (*adresses)[128])
```

to be able to pass your two dimensional array correctly and `fscanf` should scan into your actual line buffer and if you are reading line by line use `fgets`:

```
while(fgets(adresses[i], 128, fr)) i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

when you pass `adresses[1024][128]` to a function, the compiler will only do one step of decay, and the parameter type should be `char (*)[128]` instead of `char **` .

You also need to pass its first dimension to the function, which means

int getAdresses(char (int (*arr)[128], int x)

[check the c-faq for a detailed explanation for this issue.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html)

Answer (score 0):

The array you allocated declaring

```
char adresses[1024][128]
```

is actually a `char*` (it isn't but it's much closer to it than to `char**`).

The double diemension accessor is actually just a syntactic sugar for `[x+y*width]`.

To pass the array as a parameter use:

```
int getAdresses(char (*adresses)[128])
```